# On the existence of a special Hardy inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, sobolev-spaces

It is well-known that the following Hardy inequality holds:
\begin{equation}
\frac{(N-2)^2}{4}\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}\frac{u^2}{|x|^2}\,dx\leq\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}|\nabla u|^2\,dx,\quad\quad\forall\,u\in\mathcal{D}^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^N),
\end{equation}
where $\mathcal{D}^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ is the completion of $C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R}^N)$ under the norm $\|u\|^2=\int\,|\nabla u|^2$.

My question is that is there exist the reverse type inequality of the above inequality? Or, equivalently, whether the following proposition holds for some constant $C>0$:

\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}|\nabla u|^2\,dx\leq C\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}\frac{u^2}{|x|^2}\,dx,\quad\quad\forall\,u\in\mathcal{D}^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^N).
\end{equation}

I guess this conjecture is wrong, but I can't construct a counter-example. Any hints will be appreciated!

Comment: Could you please remind what is $\mathcal{D}^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^N)$?

Comment: Not true. For $N=1$, take $u_n(x) = \sin(n\pi x)$ on $(1,2)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got it!!

Comment: Clearly not true, imagine $u$ is $0$ in a ball of size $1$ around $0$. Then your inequality would imply
$$
\int |\nabla u|^2 \leq C\int |u|^2
$$
which is obviously false for a function with a discontinuity for example, since it makes appear a measure such as a Dirac delta in $\nabla u$.